# Best way to extend Core class comparison methods

Tags: ruby, coding-style, rubygems, overriding, conventions

I'd like my class to be [complete](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/018-Complete_Class.html) for several anticipated scenarios, including object comparison. My class is `Hash`-like in that it has a method `to_hash`, on which many of my class-completing methods are based. For example:

```
class Hashlike
  def == other
    if other.respond_to?(:to_hash)
      to_hash == other.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

It seems overkill to override `Hash#==` just to inject similarity into the message's superchain:

```
class Hash
  def == other
    # Flip the comparison
    other.is_a?(Hashlike) ? other == self : super
  end
end
```

This will end up in stacktraces everywhere for entirely irrelevant issues. This feels invasive.

Is there a preferred or less invasive way to make `Hash` aware of my `Hashlike`'s eligibility for comparison? And in general, is there a convention for extending core objects (`Hash`, `Array`) to receive core interface messages (`==`, `nil?`, `<==>`) and be aware of custom classes without leaving fingerprints all over their superchains?

**Update:**

The only optimization that occurs to me is to make the override call super *first* in the hopes of not choking a potentially heavily-used method with early conditional branching:

```
class Hash
  def == other
    # Lazily delay the comparison
    super or (other == self if other.is_a?(Hashlike))
  end
end
```

Some careful benchmarking (to the order of 1 billion comparisons) suggests that using either approach performs just as well as ruby's default of reversing the comparison if `to_hash` is defined on the received object, as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash already does this. If an object responds to `to_hash`, `Hash#==` should do `other == self` to allow for this sort of thing.